# How to display columns from two tables in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Right. So I am new to MVC.

I have two tables. tblCustomer_Details and tblCustomer_Location. There is a relationship between the two tables by CustomerID.

Now, how do I display few columns from one table and few from others?

I have tried using View Model. I created a new model named ViewModel and added Lists of both tables.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Are you using MVC with c# and Razor? Because you can just loop through your model on the page using Razor syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507261/looping-through-model-with-razor

Comment: Awesome take a look at my link and let us know if that helped.